# How to reduce rows to their frequencies?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframes where rows consist of two strings, user id A and user id B:

```
1234, 3456
1234, 5678
3456, 1234
1234, 3456
```

I want to transform that to something like:

```
1234: (3456, 2), (5678, 1)
3456: (1234, 1)
```

So one row per unique column A value, and the count of how many times each unique column B value appeared in a row with that unique column A value.

If I filtered down to just one user ID in column A, I know I could get how often each other user id appeared in column B with:

```
df.rdd.map(lambda row: (row['columnB'], 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
```

But as a Spark n00b, I can't figure out how to do that for all users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to aggregate

```
from pyspark.sql.functions immport *

cnts = df.groupBy("columnA", "columnB").count()
```

and [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=collect_list#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list):

```
cnts.groupBy("columnA").agg(collect_list(struct(col("columnA"), col("count"))))
```